# How to share post on Facebook with image in vue CLI (SPA)?

Tags: meta-tags, vue-cli-3, facebook-share, socialshare

I am creating project in Vue CLI 3. I want to share post detail page on Facebook and twitter. I have already tried vue-social-sharing. I am not getting an image on Facebook shared post.

> I have already tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-social-sharing

Answer (score 0):

You may find that you need to add open graph tags to the head section of the page you are referring to. Facebook as well as other social networks will look for these tags and utilise them to help with sharing etc.

```
<meta property="og:url" content="YOUR_PAGE_URL" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:title" content="PAGE_TITLE" />
<meta property="og:description" content="PAGE_DESCRIPTION" />
<meta property="og:image" content="URL_TO_IMAGE" />
```

Reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/

However, unless your Vue application is SEO friendly/server rendered (such as using Nuxt). You may find that you will still run in to issues as dynamic meta tags may not be rendered.